# Tool to make screenshot-based "screencast"

Tags: linux, screencasts

I'd like to make a simple animation: some screenshots with added text. Something like screencast, but simpler, no audio... and hopefully very quick to produce--this is my main requirement.

Googling for "screencasts" gives me full-blown tools to record video and audio, and I don't need them. I found an example of what I'd like to have here: http://www.goldenplanet.com/products/typo3/features/live-demo/forms.html (I don't need that fancy mouse pointer animation though).

I can make screenshots manually, then add text in GIMP... but maybe there is something easier, quicker?

Very preferably something that works on Linux.

EDIT: [wink](http://www.debugmode.com/wink/) would be OK, but it doesn't have binaries for x64.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as the screenshots go, I have never used the full potential of Shutter http://shutter-project.org/ but it seems like you may find it to be a helpful tool.

As far as putting them together, I don't fully understand what you mean by simple animation, but Openshot http://www.openshotvideo.com/ works great (and very easily) for putting images together and exporting them to a variety of video formats.

Edit: Based on current testing, there is a batch photo album creator http://extensions.services.openoffice.org/en/project/PhotoAlbum for OpenOffice and LibreOffice (I tested) which will bring a whole directory of images automatically into Impress which can then be exported as PDF, SWF, or HTML depending on your preferences.

Comment: Shutter helps with making screenshots and editing them. It could make adding text to images easier (it doesn't add borders automatically). Still looking for something to put images together later, I don't want to make a real video out of it.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "put images together"? If it isn't a video that actually plays, would it just be a presentation, or PDF of slides? Of if you want users to just be able to click though the images, maybe one of the online photo solutions that supports slide shows is the answer so you could add comments to the images (other than the image annotations) and viewers could click forward or back.

Comment: I don't want to use online software, these screenshots are private. Yes, PDF would be ok, or a HTML with JS. I just don't want to make that manually. I will probably be making such things quite often, so I am looking for a tool for that.

Comment: I once used an OpenOffice photo album creator quiet effectively, though now have switched to LibreOffice so don't have access to it anymore http://extensions.services.openoffice.org/node/419. Since I am a Google user I use Picasa on the desktop using WINE and it works great and can also create html galleries.